# Android Listener dismiss context menu

Tags: android, listener

Problem : I'm doing

```
registerForContextMenu(list);
```

And everything is good, except ;

Problem : I want to trigger an action when the contextMenu is dismissed. How can I have a listener if the user dismiss the contextMenu ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override the method:

```
@Override
public void onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    super.onContextMenuClosed(menu);
}
```

and do whatever you want to :)

Good luck,
Arkde